# Richfaced rendering takes longer time

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

Hi we are using various combination of data table and rich combobox and tab panel. the rendering is taking too long. is i did the performance tuning suggestions from stackoverflow and other websites

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.xmlparser.ORDER</param-name>
    <param-value>NEKO</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.xmlparser.NEKO</param-name>
    <param-value>.*\..*</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.responseBufferSize</param-name>
    <param-value>500000</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>500000</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceparser</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>enable-cache</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any logic in your getters? As these will be called multiple times move all logic into methods that are called once.

Put in a [Phase Listener like this one from Andy Gibson](http://www.andygibson.net/blog/index.php/2009/06/16/timing-jsf-requests-using-a-phase-listener/)

Comment: not much logic in getmethods(). in my debugging i observed my getter method will be called only once. only render-esponse phase is taking lots and lots of time. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Notice, that by default richfaces components use client side paging based on JavaScript, so when you load a page **all data** are read. Maybe initially your page shows lot of data (table, combos, tabs)?

Try to improve performace by creating [server side paging](http://gochev.blogspot.com/2009/08/richfaces-server-side-paging-with.html).

Comment: yes my page uses small amount of data.  we are not using any pagination we have to display 100 rows at a time. the total data getting displayed is less han 100mb.